# Creating functions for excel in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, excel

In old excel visual basic it was easy to create and use a function. You create a function in Vb:

public function testing()
 testing = "this is the result" 
end function

Then in excel you put "=testing()" in your cell.

In Visual Studio 2010 I am creating a new Excel Workbook project, putting the functions code into Sheet1.vb and saving.

But in 2010 excel sheet my function is not showing up. I tried putting the code into the VisaulBaseic of the spreadsheet with the same null result.

Incredibly to me I cant find a simple example of this in the whole web, hence this call for help.

Are there new steps I am missing?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links that will walk you through the steps you need to perform.  Pretty straightforward, worked fine for me.  Give it a try.

[Walkthrough: Calling Code from VBA in a Visual Basic Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608609.aspx)

[Microsoft Office Excel Programming Using VSTO 3.0](http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-excel-programming-using-vsto)